# Consider $n\in\mathbb{N},n>1$. The sum $S=1.1^2+3.2^2+5.3^2+7.4^2+\dots+(2n-1)n^2$ converges to what value in terms of $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider $n\in\mathbb{N},n>1$. The sum $S=1.1^2+3.2^2+5.3^2+7.4^2+\dots+(2n-1)n^2$ converges to what value in terms of $n$?

I saw the answer is $\frac{n(n+1)(3n^2+n-1)}{6}$, but I don´t know how to come to that conclusion ... Can someone help me?

Comment: This is not a convergence of the sum for $n\rightarrow \infty$, it is a formula for the sum depending on $n$. You only need the sum of the first $n$ squares and the sum of the first $n$ cubes to calculate this sum.

Comment: Each term is a degree-3 polynomial so the partial sum will be a degree-4 polynomial.  So all you have to do is find it. Taking successive differences would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole lot of difference between "convergence" and a formula. $\sum_{n} n^{2}(2n-1)=\sum_{n}(2n^{3}-n^{2})=2\sum_{n}n^{3}-\sum_{n}n^{2}=2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^{2}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ .

Simplify the above yo get your required form.

You can use a proof by induction to prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n}n^{3}=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^{2}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n}n^{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. Or you can look at proofs [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Cubes) .